# Laravel 8 signature pad won't appear in hostinger

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Help me pls;< Can someone tell me why the signature pad only appears in localhost and not when deployed online i'm using hostinger.  https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-signature-pad-example-tutorialexample.html i'm using the code from here.

or someone master at laravel can recommend me what to use in laravel 8, i am needing signature pad and if submitted in form turn into image. someone have idea? :<

here is the code:

````
<head>
    <title>Laravel Signature Pad Tutorial Example - ItSolutionStuff.com </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.signature.js"></script>
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.signature.css">
  
    <style>
        .kbw-signature { width: 100%; height: 200px;}
        #sig canvas{
            width: 100% !important;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
  
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-5">
           <div class="card">
               <div class="card-header">
                   <h5>Laravel Signature Pad Tutorial Example - ItSolutionStuff.com </h5>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body">
                    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success  alert-dismissible">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>  
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('signaturepad.upload') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="" for="">Signature:</label>
                            <br/>
                            <div id="sig" ></div>
                            <br/>
                            <button id="clear" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Clear Signature</button>
                            <textarea id="signature64" name="signed" style="display: none"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    </form>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sig = $('#sig').signature({syncField: '#signature64', syncFormat: 'PNG'});
    $('#clear').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sig.signature('clear');
        $("#signature64").val('');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: have you checked on browser console (F12) for any error messages?

Comment: @BagusTesa i haven't ,wait I'll try. sorry im just newbie thanksss for ur time responding appreciated<33

Comment: @BagusTesa it says keith-wood.name/css/jquery.signature.css:1 

       Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
jquery.signature.js:1 
        
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: It generally means your security certificate is invalid or you're not using HTTPS. This is something that would have to be fixed on the end of hostinger.

Comment: i doubt its hostinger problem. @Angel is your site uses `https`? for a quick workaround, download both `jquery.signature.css` and `jquery.signature.js` then put them on your site locally. finally, update your blade view to use those locally stored files instead.

Comment: also, i doubt what you post is your actual code `keith-wood.name` on your code is referred using `http` but it complains about `https`. most likely (just a hunch), you had `https` on your end and you change all external resource links to use `https` to avoid mixed content. `keith-wood.name` do indeed uses self-signed cert..

Comment: omg, you had `upgrade-insecure-request` directive. my bad, indeed the browser tried to load `keith-wood.name` using `https` even when you wrote `http` on the url.

Comment: @BagusTesa yowwwwwwwwwwwwwwww you're the bestt! it works! i changed it with https. i think i'm gonna cryy hahhaa thank u! God bless youuu!

Comment: but the website turned to Not Secure. is it because of the links? i'm thinking they are not safe to use

Comment: @Angel did you copy keith's css and js to your own site?

Comment: @BagusTesa Yesss, and it turned Not secure when i open that page, but the signature pad is working fine on my laptop with warning Not secured. but in other device  its not rendering/working.  im screwed with my project in school :<<

Comment: is the `upgrade-insecure-request` still there? if not, is the other resources still `http` or `https`? there are a lot of questions :( it would be nice if the question has [mcve]..